How predictable are the decomposition temperatures of trithiocarbonates?
How do the following parameters:

Ionic radius of a cation.
Oxidation number of a cation.
Noble metal cation vs alkali metal cation.
Something else that I may not know about.

affect the decomposition temperatures of trithiocarbonates, when assuming the environment to be that of an Inert gas or vacuum. Thermal stabilities in air, water or any other reactive media, can be neglected.

Are there even thiocarbonates of noble metals?

@Mithoron I have no idea. That would correspond to the decomposition temperature of zero Kelvin.

@Mithoron Google search found a single mentioning of silver trithiocarbonate. I didn't find out whether it was in solution or pure solid, because the article was behind a paywall.
